# Every vue component returning Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

So I've tried researching this but none of the solutions are working. I think it's an issue with some of my vue dependencies, potentially `vue-loader`, " but I'm not sure what to do to fix it. I have tried:

- deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm install`
- `npm update`
- I've tried removing `vue-loader` completely
- tried adding, removing, and updating `@vue/component-compiler-utils`
- tried changing the version of the above to three different things
- tried running `composer install` and `composer update`
- creating a new temp staging branch from master just in case it was some weird git error and building from that

What am I missing here? Every vue component on my staging site returns this same error. The weirdest thing is that the staging server is a direct clone of our production server, where everything works completely smoothly and I get zero errors.

**The Errors:**

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/components/component.vue
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined
    at parse (/var/www/site/node_modules/@vue/component-compiler-utils/dist/parse.js:14:23)
    at Object.module.exports (/var/www/site/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js:67:22)
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js 60:29-81
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

I've tried installing these warnings' dependencies as well but still get the same error above, I'm including these because it's what pops up when I run my bash script and run npm install from my staging branch:

```
npm WARN eslint-plugin-vue@5.2.3 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-eslint-parser@5.0.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

**package.json dependencies**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^13.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.22.10",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
   "dependencies": {
    "@vue/component-compiler-utils": "^3.1.1",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "braces": "^2.3.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "luxon": "^1.12.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-datetime": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "vue-datetime-picker": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-full-calendar": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.8.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10",
    "vue-wysiwyg": "^1.7.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0",
    "weekstart": "^1.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4",
    "wkhtmltopdf": "^0.3.4"
  }
}
```

I think it might have something to do with a specific version of a dependency. But nothing I've been trying from other stack overflow threads or Google searches has been helping

Let me know if there's any code missing that may help

Comment: Can you show the code with using 'parseComponent'?

Comment: Is this your component ./resources/assets/js/components/component.vue or system?

Comment: the component is the first one, and the thing using ``parseComponent`` is the dependency I believe, I don't have ``parseComponent`` in any of my components

Comment: Have you checked this issue https://github.com/eddyerburgh/parcel-vuejs-template/issues/11 ?

Comment: @webprogrammer yes I tried rolling that dependency back to that suggested version but i still get the same error

Comment: And this https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1490 ?

Comment: @webprogrammer yeah I've tried 1.3.1 and 2.0 and 3+ for that dependency and all of them cause the same error

Comment: @movac have you solved it? I have the same problem, that dependency auto-updates so I cannot force it

Comment: @clod986 sorry just saw this, yes changing the versions was the only thing that helped me, is there a way you can prevent auto updating?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I had exacly the same problem and just figured it out, I hope this helps someone.
First I changed the vue template compiler to:

> "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.11"

and the I also had to change the vue version to the latest realese, in my case:

> "vue": "2.6.11"

Comment: Can confirm the issue for me was with old versions of vue-loader and vue-template-compiler

Answer (score 18):

Try running this command

```
npm update vue-template-compiler
```

Comment: did not wirk with me :-(

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
npm remove vue-template-compiler

npm remove vue
```

then

```
npm install vue-template-compiler@2.6.11

npm install vue@2.6.11
```

This will match the version of vue and vue-template compiler on your project.

Answer (score 11):

The version of "vue-template-compiler" should match the version of "vue". If the dependency is declared as:

```
"vue": "^2.6.11"
```

Npm will possibly install vue@2.6.12, which is mismatched with the version of "vue-template-compiler". As of what updates between 2.6.11 and 2.6.12, you can refer to the release notes.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I ran the command: `npm update vue-template-compiler`. All solved.

Answer (score 2):

For yarn:

```
yarn remove vue vue-template-compiler
yarn add vue vue-template-compiler
```

yarn upgrade seemed to have errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your project worked before, but then a subsequent install caused errors, another thing you can try instead of upgrading `vue-template-compiler` is to pin the vue build dependency versions in your package.json by using exact version numbers in `dependencies` or `devDependencies`, and in `overrides` to force sub-dependencies to their minimum specific versions where they were surely known to work.