# npm error transpileDependencies.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

When I try to run my program I get the following error:
[image]

I deleted and reinstalled node, but it still gives this error.

Comment: did you delete *lock.json along the node_modules?

Comment: No I don’t delete lock.json file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I faced this problem today. It was a project I was working on without any remote version so I didn't use Github.
To solve this problem, I compared "important files" on my project with those on another project where I was not having this issue.
By "important files", I mean `package.json` and all config files.

To solve this, I changed the version of `@vue/cli-plugin-babel` to `"~5.0.0"`.

`package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
"vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~3.0.0" }
```

Then I deleted the `node_modules` folder. And finally I ran the command:

```
npm i
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Try to add explanations or sources on why you updated the package version. Something like a CHANGELOG link would do the trick

Answer (score 2):

If you pulled your project from Github or somewhere else, you probably lost something. Just download it again and fix it.
Cause of error: Project lost file!

Answer (score 1):

If you have used VS or VS code to clone the repository you may face this error. Delete the repository folder in local and try to clone repository again using Git clone command.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the kong-admin-ui folder and cloned the repo again (https://github.com/pocketdigi/kong-admin-ui).
Then I did the followings (you need to install node and npm before running the npm commands):

```
cd /kong-admin-ui

npm install

nmp run serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same issue, the solution is to upgrade the compiler in the `package.json` & `package-lock.json` files.

This worked for me ->

```
"vue-template-compiler": "2.6.11"
```

All credit  goes to -> [Sayil Aguirre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62102017/4206951)

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2637#issuecomment-874606976) worked for me

`add transpileDependencies: [] in vue.config.js`

e.g.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    transpileDependencies: []
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same error in Node.js v16.14.2.
This error hasn't seen anymore after I've downgraded the version of Node.js to 16.13.2.
Please check your version.

Comment: Note NVM is the solution if you need/want to run multiple versions of node on one machine. NVM4WIN = port for windows. Great for supporting legacy frontend projects while still being able to run nodeJs LTS.